# Notice: Undefined variable Warning: mysqli_query() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli, string given

Tags: php, html, mysql, mysqli

tengo este código en registro.php pero al obtener los valores del formulario de index.php cuando los ingreso no se agregan a la base de datos.

```
<?php
//conexion con la base de datos y el servidor
 $connection = mysqli_connect('localhost', 'root', "", 'formulario');
  if (!$connection) {
  die("Database connection failed: " . mysqli_connect_error());
}
// 2. Select a database to use 
$db_select = mysqli_select_db($connection, 'formulario');
 if (!$db_select) {
 die("Database selection failed: " . mysqli_error($connection));
}
//obtenemos los valores del formulario
$nombres = $_POST['nombreuser'];
$apellidos = $_POST['apellidosuser'];
$email = $_POST['emailuser'];
$pass = $_POST['pass'];
$rpass = $_POST['rpass'];

//Obtiene la longitus de un string
$req = (strlen($nombres)*strlen($apellidos)*strlen($email)*strlen($pass)*strlen($rpass)) or die("No se han llenado todos los campos");

//se confirma la contraseña
if ($pass != $rpass) {
    die('Las contraseñas no coinciden, Verifique <br /> <a href="index.html">Volver</a>');
}

//se encripta la contraseña
$contraseñaUser = md5($pass);

//ingresamos la informacion a la base de datos
mysqli_query($connection,"INSERT INTO datos (nombres,apellidos,email,password)VALUES('','$nombres','$apellidos','$email','$contraseñaUser')" or die("<h2>Error Guardando los datos</h2>"));

echo'
    <script>
        location.href="index.html";
    </script>
'
```

?>

Comment: Mandas en tu query unas comillas vacías antes de tu variable $nombres por qué?

Comment: por que veo que tu tabla tiene: nombre, apellidos. email y password (4 en total) pero luego dentro de VALUES() mandas junto con las comillas vacias 5 valores

Comment: porque mandas un valor vacio en VALUES() ,aqui : VALUES('','

Comment: Aparte de lo que te comentan, te dice que el parámetro 1 de la función mysqli_query es un string. Podrías hacer un **echo $connection** justo antes del mysli_query ? Debería darte un resultado tipo Resource #x, pero si te devuelve algún texto, es por eso que falla.

Answer (score 0):

este fue el error que pude notar, primenramente deberias meter en una variable la sentencia **mysqli_query**  y sengundo no entiendo por que lo de las comillas vacias ya que estas haciendo referencia a un campo que no existe

```
mysqli_query($connection,"INSERT INTO datos (nombres,apellidos,email,password)VALUES('','$nombres','$apellidos','$email','$contraseñaUser')" or die("<h2>Error Guardando los datos</h2>"));
```

lo correcto seria

```
$sql=mysqli_query($connection,"INSERT INTO datos (nombres,apellidos,email,password)VALUES('$nombres','$apellidos','$email','$contraseñaUser')" or die("<h2>Error Guardando los datos</h2>"));
```